# cakephp automatically signout users

Tags: php, cakephp

I have settings in cakephp to keep users login till 1 month of inactivity but cakephp logs users out anytime, sometimes after 1 minute of signing in. That problem was always there with my cakephp script but it was not so frequent. But these days its happening like every day. I don't know what code should I post here, if you ask me to show some code I'll later Edit my post with a code. Right now I'm posting my question from my phone, out of frustration since I just got logged out again from my website. Cakephp version is 2.x

Comment: I bet you forgot your cookieTime setting. See [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/02/more-persistent-sessions-in-cake2-x/#-update-2013-06:-insight-in-the-cake-session-handling) for details.

Comment: Or maybe your browser is deleting the cookies?
Might try it with a different browser as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a missing javascript and a css file and because of the 404 error cakephp was creating problem.when I fixed those 404 errors, it's working fine now.